# React state copying it's reference ES6 way also not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I have a method where i am copying react state in to a variable using ES6 way and passing that varriable to another function where apply changes to that copied variable and changes are applying to parent variable even when i am trying ES6 way

```
 saveComponent=async  ()=>{
        let {eId,component,jObj}=this.state;
        let parentOptions=[];
        component.options.map((o, i) => {
            o.name = component.name;
            return o;
        });
        jObj = this.addUpdate(eId, component, jObj);
        parentOptions = this.treeRef.current.getParentOption(jObj);
        await this.setState({jObj: jObj, component: this.getComponentObject(), parentOptions: parentOptions});
        const sObj=[...this.state.jObj];
        console.log(sObj === jObj);
        console.log("return false but still jObj updating on change sObj");
        this.treeRef.current.reset();
        this.refPF.current.updateFormPreview(sObj);
    }
```

as you can see above that

```
sObj === jObj return false
```

but still when update sobj inside **updateFormPreview** function it is updating jObj dont know why

my updateFormPreview function is here

```
   updateFormPreview=(jsonObject)=> {
        let form=[],jObject=[];
        this.state.initObject=[...jsonObject];
        form = this.expandArray([...jsonObject]);
        form=this.setPostion(form);
        jObject=this.setDefaulValue(form)
        this.setState({jObject:jObject});
        form = form.filter(e => e.parentId === "");
        form=this.convertJson(form);
        this.setState({form:form,cObject:form});
    }
```

When i do comment calling function **updateFormPreview** jObj is not updating this means only that function update jObj
Please help me Thanks Much!!

Comment: can you share how you are implementing these codes? They seem to be ok. Are you sure you are passing the correct object to updateFormPreview?

Comment: i just copy code from file of mine and share here i can share code on email send you email

Comment: also i can show things on any desk if you want

Comment: Where are you using the saveComponent function. Show us how you are using it

Comment: please check this link http://rusherp.com/createFaq.js 
this is component where i am using saveComponent  function